# Происхождение интернет-мема "капитан Очевидность"

Tags: сленг

Может быть, я очень отстала от жизни, но происхождение большинства интернет-мемов мне не понятны, хотя среди них встречаются довольно любопытные.
Например, интересно, откуда пошло это — "капитан Очевидность", либо производное от него "спасибо, кэп" (пишут, когда кто-то изрекает или пишет очевидную для всех вещь).

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос, теперь буду знать, к чему в ответах этот "кэп". Сам вопрос К.О. приписать никак нельзя!

Comment: >Сам вопрос К.О. приписать никак нельзя!

@DocentI, капитан Очевидность вопросы не задаёт, он на них отвечает. Вроде ответов на детские загадки подобные этой.

-По чему утка плавает?  
-По воде.

Comment: Вы, наверное, не поняли автора этого фото. Он имел в виду горку, которая примыкает к балкону, с которого хозяин каждый раз выходит из дома не через дверь, а прямо с горки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Калька с английского Captain Obvious. Там, образ возник по аналогии с персонажами комиксов Капитан Америка, Капитан Галактика и им подобных. Супергерой, приходящий на помощь, при необходимости объяснить то, что и так всем понятно.

> — Скажите, пожалуйста, куда мне отсюда идти?
> — А куда ты хочешь попасть? — ответил Кот.
> — Мне всё равно… — сказала Алиса.
> — Тогда всё равно, куда и идти, — заметил Кот.
> — …только бы попасть куда-нибудь, — пояснила Алиса.
> — Куда-нибудь ты обязательно попадёшь, — сказал Кот. — Нужно только достаточно долго идти

Капитан Очевидность в виде Чеширского кота из сказки Льюиса Кэролла.

Comment: За ответ плюсую, а дальше хочу поворчать. Извините, немножко отрицательных эмоций.

Что-то не нравится мне это выражение -- *капитан Очевидность*. Как-то совсем не по-русски. Как встречу в Интернете, так даже раздражает.

Comment: А если принять наличие в нём доли стёба? Тогда он продолжит ряд с Неуловимым Джо. 

Comment: >Как-то совсем не по-русски.  
   
Почему, Nikolja?
Чем это хуже, скажем, Резидента Утина? 
Согласен, на английском звучит лучше, ибо воспринимается как фамилия...
Но на английском, простите был, например, и майор Майор Майор...

Comment: >Согласен, на английском звучит лучше, ибо воспринимается как фамилия...

И это тоже. Одно дело произнести У-тин, два слога, другое дело какая-то О-че-вид-ность. Для фамилии странновато.

Потом -- **капитан**. Хуже того -- **кэп**. Что за капитан? Почему капитан? Риторический вопрос. Нет, не по душе.

:) Странное дело. Непонятное дело.

Comment: Ответ принципиально правильный, но за Алису минусую - ну вот вообще никаким боком тут этот диалог, там нет ничего очевидного.

Comment: @stopkran, Ваше право. Если вы считаете, что мысль о неизбежности прихода куда-нибудь при движении куда-то, Вам не кажется очевидной, то видимо так оно и есть. Приношу извинения за доставленный Вам дискомфорт.

Comment: Да уж! Чеширский кот говорит все точно, но совершенно не очевидно!

Comment: @Яzz, это не КО, а заумь или ирония. Если автор осознаёт очевидность высказывания, его нельзя уже отнести к КЭПам. Вы же не добавите сюда ещё и вариант Алисы Высоцкого:

\- А почему это место - "очень странное место"?

\- Да потому, дитя моё, что все другие места - очень уже не странные!

Тоже ведь "всё очевидно".

Comment: @stopkran, у Высоцкого нет очевидности, так как то, что остальные места не странные нам может быть неизвестно. КО же менторским тоном пишет о том, что всем известно и без него, в том числе и самому спрашивающему. КО на вопрос из Вашего примера, ответил бы "Потому, что тут происходят очень странные вещи".

То о чём говорил Чеширский кот, Алисе было и без него, поэтому под "кэпа", в данном диалоге, он вполне подпадает.

Comment: @docent, Чеширский кот говорит вещи как раз очевидные. Не банальные, но очевидные и без его слов.

Comment: Классно клоны расчирикались! Чеширские бегемотусы, один за другим, понужают и понужают))) Скоро на шабаш, тренируют слетанность.

Comment: Не вижу из диалога Алисы и Кота образа КО. Ответы Кота адекватны вопросам Алисы (коль она их задаёт!).

Comment: @Hermit, а с чего ответы не должны быть адекватными? Они вполне себе адекватны, но очевидны, т.е. все согласны, что утверждения кота верны, отвечают на поставленный вопрос, и при этом абсолютно бесполезны, так как они и без того известны.

Comment: Nikolja, меня вообще большинство интернет-мемов раздражает. Отчасти потому, что я не знаю ни их происхождения, ни их значения. Так что, за такие вопросы благодарна)))

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот, типичный пример применения этого мема (об отсутствии запятой в обоих случаях деликатно умолчим)))):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> и при этом абсолютно бесполезны, так
> как они и без того известны.

Иногда на *странный* вопрос (Алисы, например) и нужно ответить буквальной очевидностью как залогом и надеждой для синхронизации начала понимания. Что, по-моему, и делает Кот.

Comment: Этим и занимается Капитан Очевидность. Очевидные ответы, как правило, и даются на некорректные вопросы. Однако от этого они не становятся менее очевидными. Однако тут это оффтопик, поэтому попрошу ответить в вопросе по ссылке. http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/23171/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Вообще, "Спасибо, кэп" пишут, когда, например, на двери написано "дверь" или еще что-то в этом роде.